# bit manipulation in java

Tags: java, numbers, byte, math, bitwise-operators

I have a fragment of bytes in a byte[]. The total size of the array is 4 and I want to convert this into a positive long number. For example if the byte array is having four bytes 101, 110, 10, 10000001 then i want to get the long number represented by binary sequence

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000101 00000110 00000010 10000001
```

which equals 84279937

What is the efficient way to do that in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming little-endian,

```
(b[0] & 0xFF) | (b[1] & 0xFF) << 8 | (b[2] & 0xFF) << 16 | (b[3] & 0xFF) << 24
```

Example, http://www.ideone.com/p68zS

The `& 0xFF` is there to convert the signed bytes into unsigned...

Comment: I assume you meant bytes[3] | bytes[2] << 8 | bytes[1] << 16 | bytes[0] << 24 , as I want the first byte as the most significant.

if i do this I am getting 

111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000001

This is the problem i want to solve. The last byte is treated as negative and when it is left shifted 24 bits, the first 40 bit are set to 1

Comment: @sarav: If you want to keep the sign of the last byte, just omit the last `& 0xFF`.

Comment: @sarav: Those `& 0xFF` **are** deliberately added to prevent `...1111111110000001`.

Comment: Sorry I missed the `& 0xFF` .. didnt refresh the page to see your updated answer. It worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about efficiency, but since [one of BigInteger's constructors](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28byte[]%29) gets a byte array, this may be a very simple way:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

...

long value = new BigInteger(myByteArray).longValue();
```

Of course, you must take care that the bytes are given in two's complement and be aware that they are given in most-significant-byte first - so in your case you probably want to pad the beginning of your array with another 4 empty bytes.

Answer (score 2):

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(8); 
buf.put(4, b[0]).put(5, b[1]).put(6, b[2]).put(7, b[3]);
long longVal = buf.getLong();
```